# trying to get a site to access localhost:(port) rather than localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, portforwarding, port80

Sorry if this has been asked and answered elsewhere, but I haven't seen it.

I'm trying to set up a database system to learn to code in PHP and use MySQL but I've had some problems. I am using XAMPP and, because I am using a Windows 10 machine, the default port for local host was reserved for Skype so I set everything to use port 9030 instead. Everything works until I try to run any PHP code that tries to connect with a (local) database (for example, I make a "new user" type of form that I want to add a new user to a database). When I submit the info, the page won't load and the loading notifier on the bottom of the (Chrome) window shows "waiting for localhost". I'm assuming this means that my program is trying to access port 80 instead of 9030 (rather than my code being just wrong). The program works fine on a relative's computer who is running his server on an XP machine that doesn't have the port issue in the first place and the program also works fine with the site until I attempt anything dealing with the database.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: "I'm assuming this means that my program is trying to access port 80 instead of 9030 " — Don't assume these things. Test them. Look at the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Look at the URL that is being requested.

Comment: Are you sure it's Skype and not IIS?

Comment: On command line, run: "netstat -ano" and see who is listening to what port. You will see PID and identify the PID using task manager. Can you connect to mysql over terminal using localhost or 127.0.0.1? Try changing mysql host as 127.0.0.1 in your php script.

Answer (score -1):

' **try to run any PHP code that tries to connect with a (local) database (for example, I make a "new user" type of form that I want to add a new user to a database). When I submit the info, the page won't load and the loading notifier on the bottom of the (Chrome) window shows "waiting for localhost"** '. 
According to this, you created a form and on submitting it is not working. If I am correct, then please check the action method in your form. Because ' **the loading notifier on the bottom of the (Chrome) window shows "waiting for localhost"** ' would never show errors like this if it is unable to connect to the mysql server. So please check the action method in your form. It might be having **http://localhost/your_submit_page.php**. Make it **http://localhost:port/your_submit_page.php**